# Transparency support with PNGs in conversions for spatie/media-library

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-medialibrary

I am using `spatie/media-library` with my `Laravel 8` project. In the model, I am writing a method to register a `mediaCollection` for a model. The issue I am facing is that during the conversion, the transparency is lost in the converted image.

How can I resize the image without losing transparency in result image?

Here is the code that I am using

```php
    public function registerMediaCollections(): void
    {
        $this->addMediaCollection('crops')
            ->singleFile()
            ->useDisk('public')
            ->acceptsMimeTypes([
                'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg',
            ])
            ->onlyKeepLatest(1)
            ->registerMediaConversions(function (Media $media) {
                $this
                    ->addMediaConversion('thumb')
                    ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 150, 150)
                    ->keepOriginalImageFormat();
            });
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Ehs4n did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can add ->keepOriginalImageFormat() in registerMediaConversions

So when you upload a transparent .png file, it will keep the transparent background

Comment: It doesn't respect transparency and creates white background for it.

Comment: Which image format @Ehs4n, currently it works for me perfectly